# Is there a generic way to parallelize algorithms?

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, parallel-computing

Take:

- An algorithm $A$ that is analytically nice in some way, say, for some class of inputs of length $n$ it runs at $O(f(n))$ on some Turing machine.
- $k+2$ independent, identical such machines.

Is there a generic method to produce algorithms $A_{in}, A_{out}, A_{1},\dots, A_k$ for which tapes can be made so that:

- $A_{in}$ finishes after $O(k)$ and transforms a length-$n$ input for $A$ into $k$ inputs, each to one of $A_\ell$, $\ell \in \{1,\dots, k\}.$
- Each $A_\ell$ runs in $O(f(n)/k)$
- $A_{out}$ runs in $O(k)$ and combines the the outputs of the $A_\ell$ into what $A$ would have produced on the input of $A_{in}$

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel, thanks for the references. I might move the question. Are there algorithms where allowing for communication between rounds achieves a strictly lower complexity class than any non-communicating scheme could?

Comment: It depends. Barrington’s theorem shows that the word problem for $\bar{A}_5$ (or $\bar{S}_5$) is complete for $NC^1$ (under deterministic logtime many-one reductions). "The solution of that word problem is nicely scalable, since one can subdivide the word into smaller parts, and thereby generate a smaller word on which the same procedure can be applied again." But that word problem can be solved by your single round scheme just as fast. But the typical parallel algorithms work in rounds nevertheless. And the memory consumption would be awful, if Barrington's theorem would be used in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there cannot be such a generic method to produce algorithms $A_{in}, A_{out}, A_{1},\dots, A_k$ with the requested properties. The basic problem is that the requested parallel algorithm only uses a single round. (And allowing $A_{in}$ and $A_{out}$ only $O(k)$ time is very restrictive, they cannot even read length-$n$ input or write a length-$n$ output in that time.)

One simple problem which even has a parallel algorithm (but not of the form stated in the question) is the **all-prefix-sums** operation. Input is a list of numbers, and output is another list, whose elements are the sum of all previous elements in the original list. See section "3.2 Scans" on page 23 in

Parallel Algorithms (64 pages)
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/BM04.pdf
by Guy E. Blelloch and Bruce M. Maggs – 1996

---

There are at least two possible criticisms of this answer. (1) The counter-example problem took a list of size $n$ and output a list of size $n$. Maybe the question expected the output to be much shorter than the input, like in a decision problem. (2) No explicit proof is given that the counter-example problem has no parallel algorithm of the form stated in the question.

Regarding (1), an output of length-$n$ is used to get around Barrington's theorem, as explained in a comment below the question. Regarding (2), one might look at the elements from $n/2$ to $n$ of the output. Each of them would require more than $n/2$ additions, if computed in isolation. $A_{out}$ can only output $O(k)$ of them in $O(k)$ time, so most of them must be computed in partial isolation. Hence, the algorithms $A_i$ outputting them will need more than $O(n/2)$ time.

Answer (score 1):

No.  There are some problems that appear to be inherently sequential and not amenable to a speedup on a parallel computers.  See, e.g., https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/606/351 and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5962/351.  These schemes cannot be parallelized much, assuming certain cryptographic hardness assumptions are true.

You might also be interested in [P-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete), which are good candidates to be hard to parallelize (see also the [NC complexity class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_%28complexity%29)).

Comment: I suspect that we read the question differently.  I read "_Is there a generic way to parallelize algorithms?_" as "_What's the general strategy for parallelizing algorithms?_", which would be the data flow stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use [data-flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis), e.g. [like this](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/%7Ekal/PLT/PLT9.6.1.html):

[image],

where you trace out the causal flow of effect.

Then, where ever a node forks, that'd be $A_{\text{in}}$ in your notation.  And whenever there's a join, then that'd be $A_{\text{out}}$.  Each route between a fork and a join would be another $A_i$.

Practically speaking, most computer code can be parallelized pretty easily.  The problem's that small parallelizations tend to induce far more overhead than they're worth, effectively slowing down the code.

It's often possible to parallelize further.  But, obviously, you can't do things out-of-order unless you know a way to rewrite them.  So, one common strategy for increased parallelization effectiveness is to rewrite the code with longer routes before split paths rejoin.

---

#### Maximum parallelization

> Each $A_\ell$ runs in $O(f(n)/k)$

This notation's not quite correct, but it looks like you meant "*$k$-times faster*", i.e. a [speed-up ratio](http://www.bu.edu/tech/support/research/training-consulting/online-tutorials/matlab-pct/scalability/) of $k$ (also known as a 100% parallelization efficiency).

Anyway, that's possible if the problem can be broken into an initial fork and a final join.  That's the ideal limit which can only be reached in such a special case.  Obviously, most algorithms won't fall into that special case, so usually the speed-up ratio will be less than $k$.

Comment: The overhead can be reduced a little bit by replicating computation instead of having synchronization or communication between execution units. On a supercomputer one has the hardware exclusively, so there is no gain in having idle cores. In the diagrams this will probably become duplication of the relevant sections.

Comment: Regarding "The problem's that small parallelizations tend to induce far more overhead than they're worth, effectively slowing down the code." This is a fault of current parallel architectures. At least Uzi Vishkin argued in this direction, even presenting FPGA based hardware without that flaw. See [my reply to YOUSEFY in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41538012#41538012).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.  The question asks whether there is a way to run the algorithm on $k$ computes, in a way that reduces the total amount of time spent by a factor of $k$.  Your scheme might not allow for $k$-fold speedup.  For instance, for a sequential computation, we might not get any speedup at all.

Comment: @D.W. That was part of my point.  It's possible to get a $k$-factor speedup when the data flow can be converted to such a form, either because it's already interpretable that way or because it can be rewritten that way.  But, if the individual nodes are black boxes in a sequence, then it's strictly impossible to parallelize.  No more general specification of rewriting strategy can be made because rewriting strategies are physics-dependent and thus any further specification would necessarily be at a loss of generality.

Comment: I'm not convinced.  One particular algorithm (data-flow diagram) for the problem might not be parallelizable, but there still might be another algorithm that *is* parallelizable.  Consider the task of summing $n$ numbers.  Imagine a data flow diagram that sequentially sums the numbers (first add $x_1 + x_2$, then add $x_3$ to the result, etc.).  This data-flow diagram won't be parallelizable.  But that doesn't mean that it's impossible to parallelize the task; in fact, it *can* be parallelized if you change the algorithm.  So your transformation isn't enough to solve the problem in all cases.

Comment: @D.W. That's a rewrite, which uses the physics of the nodes when they're not black boxes (e.g., when they're `+`'s).  Rewritten forms can be attempted by searching over the space of a walk from the original wherein steps are legal transforms, but that's a physics-dependent process, such that rearrangements like the one you'd proposed aren't [always appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa).

Comment: I'm not sure what set of rewrite rules you're proposing, but I'm not sure there's any set of rewrite rules that (a) is guaranteed to preserve correctness, and (b) lets you get from any correct algorithm for a task to every other correct algorithm for the task.  Certainly finding a parallelizable algorithm is not something you can do efficiently in the worst case; it might not even be decidable.  For instance, whatever set of rewrite rules you have in mind, will they transform a trial division algorithm for primality testing to the AKS primality testing algorithm?

Comment: (Not sure what physics-dependent means.)

Comment: @D.W. I'm confused by your last comment.  As I'd said in my first comment above, rewriting rules are physics-dependent such that we can't broadly speak of any set of rewrite rules that'll always apply.  For example, how a division algorithm might be rewritten is dependent upon the context; we can't broadly speak to how it might be done in all cases.

Comment: @D.W. Oh, "_physics-dependent_" is kinda like "_instruction-set-dependent_" or "_library-dependent_" or "_language-dependent_".  Basically a computer can be any systematic configuration that does jobs of some type, where the instructions that it can perform are dictated by its physics.  So, whenever you can transform something like a `+` operation, the details behind that transform are based on maintaining the same physical operation, from the perspective of the user.